# Aligning text with picture

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-recyclerview

I have the following recyclerview. And as you can see,the text is not aligned with the image in each row.

[image: my screenshot]

And my xml for this is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="2dp"
android:id="@+id/relLayout">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/article_title"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/networkImage"/>

<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:id="@+id/networkImage"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas why is this happening?

Thanks,

Theo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the attribute `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` for your `TextView` and it should be vertically centered.

Comment: yes. that's good now. What if I want the text to be next to the top right of th e image?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand but isn't right now the text to the top right of the image?